# JIT compiler optimization: second method call with same parameter

Tags: java, validation, optimization, parameters, jit

Say I have a method that is used to validate specific values, **for example** a method `isEven`:

```
public static boolean isEven(int evenSize) {
    return evenSize % 2 == 0;
}
```

I use this method to validate external input (e.g. from disk or from users). But after that I also use this method in a method that requires even values:

```
public static String padToEven(int evenSize, String string) {
    if (!isEven(evenSize)) { // <-- duplication of isEven method
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("evenSize argument is not even");
    }

    if (string.length() >= evenSize) {
        return string;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(evenSize);
    sb.append(string);
    for (int i = string.length(); i < evenSize; i++) {
        sb.append('x');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

so basically we supply already validated parameter to the `padToEven()` and the parameter is validated using the same `isEven` function. Could it be possible for the JIT compiler (say in version 8 of Java) to find this second call and optimize it away?

You may assume that the check doesn't depend on dynamic values (i.e. it is deterministic to the supplied parameter value). It also doesn't have any side effects other than the return value such as logging statements.

Comment: Obviously for `isEven` it won't matter, but e.g. `isPrime` the difference in operation may be notable, especially when used within a loop.

Comment: Interesting question! I doubt, however, that's this is possible to determine such reuse safely in the general case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah, could be very tricky. Quite a lot of unknowns for the JIT compiler (side effects, state)  and the calls may be separated with quite a lot of byte code too.

Comment: It depends a things that you haven't mentioned, such as how that value gets into that function and the shape of the control flow between those moments. Eg if `padToEven` is called somewhere as a descendant of a function that already checked `isEven`, it is easier to reason about (but still a level of interprocedural analysis that I don't expect from a JVM) than if eg `main` calls something that reads a value, checks it, puts it into some static field, and then calls something else that involves `padToEven`. Also it depends on if the predicate can be represented by a numerical abstract domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Java does any interprocedural analysis at all. However, there are some chances that the method gets inlined. When you inline everything, then there's

```
if (evenSize % 2 != 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("evenSize argument is not even");
}
... some code not changing evenSize
if (evenSize % 2 != 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("evenSize argument is not even");
}
```

which is rather trivial to optimize. This inlining is not something you can depend on, as there's an inlining limit which gets reached rather quickly.

### Other optimizations

OTOH, the test is pretty trivial and probably gets optimized to

```
public static boolean isEven(int evenSize) {
    return (evenSize & 1) == 0;
}
```

which uses a much faster operation. But this isn't something, I'd care about (as there's a lot of other code around, so you can't gain much).

---

I guess, the best optimization would be the elimination of the `StringBuilder`. What??? Yes, seriously, a `char[]` would do:

```
char[] result = new char[evenSize];
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    result[i] = string.charAt(i);
}
for (int i = string.length(); i < evenSize; i++) {
    result[i] = 'x';
}
return new String(result);
```

Some time ago, I did some measurements showing that it should be way faster. This may have changed with recent JIT. Not to the important part:

#### What optimization makes sense here?

None at all. Unless you

- really need to improve performance
- profile it and find the culprit
- are ready to spend quite some time benchmarking and profiling

just don't do it. Luckily, JIT is optimized for clean code with short methods. It can't improve your algorithms and data structures, so that's where you can can optimize when you really need to. Microoptimizations are much less rewarding.

Your above code is fine, don't touch it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Note that the `isEven` method is just an example of a generic validation method. The only thing I asked about was the repeat of that method call. So everything up to "OTOH" is on topic. The rest is an interesting discussion about other parts of the code, which is great but doesn't answer the question. So basically the answer would be: won't be optimized, unless inlined.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've been aware about writing too much w.r.t. the question, but I did it as I thought, it may be useful. ;)

Comment: As I usually also give security advice with my crypto related answers I can hardly complain about that :) I split the answer into 3 parts, instead of 2, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course, Java *does* “interprocedural analysis”. That’s the whole point of doing inlining first and all other optimizations afterwards. So that’s only a matter of naming.

Comment: I doubt that dealing with the `char` array manually gains anything, even with older JVMs. Also, when dealing with the array manually, there is no reason why the first loop repeatedly calling `charAt` should be faster than a single `string.getChars(0, string.length(), result, 0)` call…

Comment: @Holger *"interprocedural analysis"* - Sure, in this sense, it does. +++ `char[]` - I'm perfectly sure, I measured it and it helped a lot. It may be five yours ago and I may have done something wrong (but it's not that complicated and I was using Caliper). +++ `string.getChars` - I didn't know this overload.